# Fieldsets with back-referencing other tables related to the User table

Tags: python, django

I have been working on this admin page where the admin can take a look at each customer's entrance of a specific endpoint. So far, I successfully created the list display where it shows how many times a customer visited this endpoint. Below is the screenshot:
[image: admin page users list]

However, my client stipulates that the details of each visit must be recorded and shown on the admin's page (e.g. the time/date when the customer visited) So I created a separate table called "Count" with the foreignkey that points at the user like so:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    level       = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

class Count(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='counts')
    date_time   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'counts'
```

The problem is when I try to show the date/time details of each visit on each customer's admin page. The admin.py looks like this so far:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from .forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm
from .models import User, Count


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    list_display = ('email', 'level', 'is_admin', 'is_active', 'user_counts')
    def user_counts(self, x):
        return x.counts.count()
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('level', 'user_counts_detail')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin', 'is_active')}),
    )
    def user_counts_detail(self, x):
        return x.counts

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'level', 'password1', 'password2')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

When I migrate and run the server, there is no error showing. But when I access the specific customer's page, some error turns up. Below is the screenshot of the error.

[image: django admin error page]

I am assuming this has to do with the "fieldsets" in admin.py but I have no idea what went wrong. How should I fix this error?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: you should use double underscores for relation traverse not one in your codes it's one under score both should be `user__counts` and `user__counts_detail` but i don't see any `detail` in your count model perhaps you meant `date_time`?

Answer (score 1):

`x.counts` follows reverse relationship and returns a **`RelatedManager`** object, if you would like to get the total counts, you need to further use **`count`** method

```
def user_counts_detail(self, x):
     return x.counts.count()  # or x.counts.all().count()

user_counts_detail.short_description = 'User count'
```